# bash if statement keeps changing second argument to literal string

Tags: bash, if-statement

So I'm not sure why it's doing this. My if statement keeps interpreting the second variable as a literal string instead of a variable. Below is my exact code.

```
lights() {
  bulb1state=$(gatttool -b D8:6F:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-read -a 0x001b)
  echo $bulb1state
  bulb2state=$(gatttool -b DA:5A:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-read -a 0x001b)
  bulb3state=$(gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:07:39:E9 --char-read -a 0x0018)
  bulb4state=$(gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:08:40:50 --char-read -a 0x0018)
  offstate="Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00"
  echo $bulb1state
  echo $offstate
  if [ "$offstate" = "$bulb1state" ]; then
    echo $bulb1state
    echo "bulb1 state = off"
    gatttool -b D8:6F:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-write -a 0x001b -n ff000000
    gatttool -b DA:5A:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-write -a 0x001b -n ff000000
    gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:07:39:E9 --char-write -a 0x0018 -n ff000000
    gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:08:40:50 --char-write -a 0x0018 -n ff000000
  fi
}
```

My output:

```
>lights
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
```

I don't understand why the last 2 echo statements are not displaying.

Edits:
There was a white space on bulb1state. This is good enough for me to find a work around but I'm still curious as why the second term of the if statement was being interpreted as a literal string when I used the "`=`" operator as opposed to the "`-eq`" operator. It also didn't matter which variable was first or second.

after accounting for the whitespace at the end of bulb1state, using `-eq` instead of `=` yielded the following output:

```
>lights
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
#Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00#
#Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00#
bash: [[: Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00: syntax error in expression (error token is "value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00")
```

Comment: Quote your variables in the echos, there could be a newline in there.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini The three echos are in the output... ??

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question

Comment: `-eq` is for numbers

Answer (score 1):

Actually from the your output you should not conclude which `echo` got printed, but lets assume that it's the right ones.

You might want to try

```
echo "#${offstate}#"  
echo "#${bulb1state}#"
```

To see if any of them (likely the `${bulb1state}` one) might have a trailing whitespace...

Comment: There was a white space on bulb1state. This is good enough for me to find a work around but I'm still curious as why the second term of the if statement was being interpreted as a literal string when I used the "=" operator as opposed to the "-eq" operator. It also didn't matter which variable was first or second.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `[[` instead of `[` ? I also suggest to take a look at this [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/067) if white-spaces are indeed the problem.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein No, that didn't help any as far as the second argument is concerned

Comment: Notice that you're using `-eq` to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `offstate` is a fixed string, you could use the `=~` operator:

```
if [[ "$bulb1state" =~ "$offstate" ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

This basically means: "if `bulb1state` contains `offstate`, then ...".